# See git diff without checking out a branch?

Tags: git

Basically I have a deployed app that I *believe* is up to date with the git repo, but I am not sure. I ran `git init` in the project root, and set the correct origin. I tested the connection and I am able to connect to the repo and get a list of branches by running `git ls-remote --heads git@myurl.git`. My question now is, is there a way to use `git diff` to see if the deployed app is in sync with a certain branch without checking out master? What exactly would git do if I ran `git checkout master`?

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the deployed app has never been tracked by git directly, it was tracked on my local machine and I would push updates by generating a tarball of all the changed files with a python gif diff script that I untar at the root of the deployed app directory. Today I set up a deploy key in gitlab so that I could just run `git pull` on the deployed app. I guess a better question would be, what's the best way to get that going? It's been a while since that app has been touched and I don't know if another developer has gone in and made untracked changes, I don't want to lose any changes that have been made to the deployed app, so I was hoping there was a way to see the difference between master and the deployed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your concern is you don't want to overwrite local changes.

No problem - just do

```
git fetch origin master
git diff FETCH_HEAD
```

or replace `master` with a different branch name above to diff against different branches.

I haven't tested this, but `git fetch` doesn't touch your working tree, and neither does `git diff`, so it should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `git diff` on branches. If you have two remotes in your repo named `remote1` and `remote2` and you want to check if a branch named `test` in the two is in sync or not just run `git diff remote1/test remote2/test`.